# How to create an aesthetically pleasant Hazard Ratio Chart in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, hazard

[image: Found This Online]

I was looking at a Youtube video I found online. I'm new to survival analysis. The host mentioned that the second graph was created using a mixture of packages Broom & ggplot2.

Any ideas?

```
# Current Code:
sigMod = coxph(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ age+anaemia+creatinine_phosphokinase+ejection_fraction+
                serum_creatinine+hypertension, data=HF)

ggforest(sigMod, data = HF)
```

**EDIT 1**

Added code so far:

```
tidy(sigMod) %>% select(term, estimate) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=estimate, y=term)) + geom_boxplot()
```

**EDIT 2**

My Model's data after using Broom:
|      Term           |     Estimate    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Age         |         0.0436065795      |
|          Anaemia1        |      0.3932590155       |
|          creatinine_phosphokinase |        0.0001964616       |
|          ejection_fraction |        -0.0517850968      |
| serum_creatinine   |   0.3483455436 |
|  hypertensionPresent    |   0.4667523759   |

Comment: Yeah, you could use `broom` to pull estimates out of a model and `ggplot` to plot them. What's you're question? Do you have a model? Have you tried anything?

Comment: tidy(sigMod) %>% select(term, estimate) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=estimate, y=term)) + geom_boxplot().

Do you know which theme is being used in my post?

Comment: Probably a custom theme. And it's not using boxplots, maybe `geom_pointrange` or `geom_errorbar` with `geom_point`. Or maybe `geom_segment`.

Comment: If you want help reproducing that plot, then you need to share some sample data. Share `dput(tidy(sigMod)[1:10])` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully reproducible example of how something like your target plot could be achieved, using the `pbc` dataset from the `survival` package. Just swap in your own `coxph` call at the start:

```r
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + ascites + spiders + hepato + edema, 
      data = pbc) %>%
  tidy() %>%
  mutate(upper = estimate + 1.96 * std.error,
         lower = estimate - 1.96 * std.error) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(c("estimate", "lower", "upper")), exp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, term, color = estimate > 1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "gray75") +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = lower, xmax = upper), size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green4", "red3"), guide = "none") +
  xlim(c(0, 5)) +
  labs(title = "Hazard ratio for various clinical findings in PBC", y = NULL,
       x = "Hazard ratio estimate (95% Confidence Intervals)") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 18))
```

[image]